# Get checkbox name from SQL Server Version 1

Tags: sql, vb.net, types, sql-server-2008-express

Problem: I'd like to retrieve the name of a checkbox from a SQL Server database table and see whether it's checked in an "if" statement.

Interface: my form consists of a listbox, a button and a checkbox.

SQL Server table:

```
ID   Name   cbName
 1   Rest   cbRest
```

I'd like to write:

```
sb = dt.rows(0)(cbName) 
    If sb.Checked() = True Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString())
    Else
        MsgBox("Nothing checked")
    End If
```

The expected output should be Rest in the listbox. Of course the next step is to loop through hundreds of checkboxes but for now I'd just like to clarify how to make this work.

Right now I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Winddows.Forms.CheckBox'

I'm using Visual Basic Express 2008 with SQL Server 2008 Express, 64 bit Windows 7 Pro

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have added your check box directly to the page you can find controls by name using `Me.Controls.Item(controlID)`, so in your case it would be

```
Dim sb as CheckBox = CType(Me.Controls.Item(dt.rows(0)("cbName")), CheckBox)
```

Comment: Thx, exactly what I was looking for, how about adding the form as well.
Let's say we're adding a column in the table; wform.
In there you have the form the checkbox belongs to.
For a checkbox in Form2:

I tried
Dim wform as Form = CType(Controls.Item(dt.rows(0)("wform")), Form)
if wform.cb.checked()...
It doesn't work

Comment: I think once you have defined the form, you would then need to access that forms `Controls` property, e.g. `Dim cb as CheckBox = CType(wform.Controls.Item(dt.rows(0)("cbName")), CheckBox)`

Comment: Dim wform As Form = CType(Controls.Item(dt.Rows(0)("wform")), Form)
            Dim cb As CheckBox = CType(wform.Controls.Item(dt.Rows(0)("cbname")), CheckBox)
If cb.Checked() = True Then
            'ListBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i)("name").ToString())
                     'End If

Comment: Post a new question and include the code used to generate the checkboxes, that will give a better idea of the code needed to reference them.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: New question with the code:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190192/get-checkbox-name-from-sql-server-version-2

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop through all your controls and find the control with id/name [cbRest]. As soon as you get hand on the control (which is a checkbox) you can use

```
If sb.Checked() = True Then
    ListBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString())
Else
    MsgBox("Nothing checked")
End If
```

where sb will be the control you found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable (sb) Here's a snippet for a button:

```
Dim btn As Button 
...
btn = CType(Controls("Button1"), Button)
```

In your case you will use the cbName value from SQL in place of "Button".

'Controls' is the parent holding the button/checkbox. The snippet works with a button on the form. If you have a container holding the checkboxes use the container_name.Controls().